# Angular 7.1 project unable to compile

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, node-sass

Some time ago I made an Angular project using angular version 7.1.4. I left it in a perfectly working state. No error whatsoever... but now after some time I have returned to that project and ran the `ng serve -o` comand and now I'm recieving this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):                                                                                                                                                                       
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
```

I see it has something to do with the node-sass dependency being deprecated if I understand the errors corectly but am unsure what to do now... any help would be apreciated... And incase I haven't provided enough info please tell me :)

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules folder and performing a clean npm install

Comment: @SecurityObscurity sorry but this doesn't resolve my issue... after deleting the node modules folder and running npm install I get the same error again

Comment: try npm uninstall node-sass && npm install node-sass

Answer (score 0):

Check out this compatibility scheme for Angular 7 requirements for node and npm https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3
If you updated any of those since you last worked on this, this might be the problem.
Downgrade to required versions, then do a npm install again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).